# 3.1.2 OSS: scheduled_execution.server_nodeuuid is NULL on job creation/save

Tags: rundeck

Is it possible for `Rundeck OSS` to work in an active/active multi-node configuration pointed to the same DB?

`scheduled_execution.server_nodeuuid` is not set at time of job creation or update of the job schedule, so, with 2 OSS Rundeck Servers running and pointed to the same DB, they each try to fire the scheduled job as `scheduled_execution.server_nodeuuid` is NULL.

For Rundeck Enterprise, this column is set to the server node that the user is working on, whenever a job is created, or its schedule attributes are updated.

Just wondering if/how multi-node active/active RD Servers are supported in OSS.

> OSS Version: 3.1.2
>
> OS: RHEL 7
>
> App Server: Apache Tomcat 9.0.6
>
> DB: MariaDB 10.1.18-1

Answer (score 0):

Not supported, if you want to build a cluster environment with Rundeck you need Rundeck Enterprise. Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/cluster/).